# passing span or label to Controller in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, view, controller

I have this script:

```
 $(this).before('<span type="text" id="id" name="name" class="tag">' + txt + '</span>');
```

But it doesn't appear in FormCollection, after I submit the form.
I assume FormCollection contains only "`<input type=...>`" tags.
So is there any way I can pass `<span>` or `<label>` from my view to a controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can pass a hidden input:

```
$(this).before('<input type="hidden" id="id" name="name" value="'+txt+' /><span type="text" id="span_id" name="span_name" class="tag">' + txt + '</span>');
```

This will add a span element, visible to the user, and an input element which is hidden from the user but will be accessible in your FormCollection

Comment: but I want the user to see it. Bassically it's a script that creates a label every time the textbox gets a ',' (http://jsbin.com/iyewas/3)
So I'm looking for a solution for it. how can I pass this information to a controller

Comment: See my edit. The `span` will be visible to the user, the hidden `input` will make it accessible to your `FormCollection` by getting the browser to send it along with the form

Comment: @KobiBurnley My provided solution will do this. I've added a matching `<input>` tag alongside your `<span>` so that you have two elements: one which your user sees and one which your server sees.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. I just put the <span> first, so when I delete it the hidden field we'll be deleted too.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a [input type='hidden']
So when you submit a form you pass the label/span value to input hidden

**And you'll see that component in the form collection.**

Hope this helps.